# R data.table fread() not bringing in entire text file completely

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working on bringing in a large dataset into R and I've discovered fread() from data.tables to be able to bring it in at a reasonable time(read.csv is really slow for me).

I am currently running into a couple issues I'd like to get some insight on. I have this "ï»¿" tag in front of the column name which I can quickly fix with a rename statement, but in addition the values that are in that column are completely different from the original file. The value should be a 16 digit identifier code (like so "1100110011001100") but when it is brought in, it comes in as "3.598E-310".

I don't know if this is due to the UTF-8 format my data is in, but I'm having some trouble figuring out what's going on. There's another variable with similar features (12 digits numerical code) that also became exponentiated. All the rest of my variables looked fine (in addition to other variables with the same length as the two variables being brought in incorrectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gotten a friendly warning:

```
library(data.table) #1.10.0

DT <- fread("1100110011001100
      1100110011001100")
#Warning message:
#In fread("1100110011001100\n      1100110011001100") :
#  Some columns have been read as type 'integer64' but package bit64 isn't loaded. Those columns will display as strange looking floating point data. There is no need to reload the data. Just require(bit64) to obtain the integer64 print method and print the data again.

print(DT)
#              V1
#1: 5.435266e-309
#2: 5.435266e-309
#Warning message:
#In print.data.table(DT) :
#  Some columns have been read as type 'integer64' but package bit64 isn't loaded. Those columns will display as strange looking floating point data. There is no need to reload the data. Just require(bit64) to obtain the integer64 print method and print the data again.

library(bit64)
print(DT)
#                 V1
#1: 1100110011001100
#2: 1100110011001100
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the OP correctly, the 16 digit identifier code is meant to be of type character.

However, `fread()` determines the column types from some sample rows (see `?fread` for details). Apparently, it tries to read the data as `integer64`. The `colClasses` parameter can be used to override the guesses made by `fread()`:

```
DT <- fread("1100110011001100
      1100110011001100", colClasses = "character")
DT
#                 V1
#1: 1100110011001100
#2: 1100110011001100
```

If the `verbose` parameter is set to `TRUE`, `fread()` reveals some of its inner workings:

```
DT <- fread("1100110011001100
      1100110011001100", colClasses = "character", verbose = TRUE)
Input contains a \n (or is ""). Taking this to be text input (not a filename)
Detected eol as \n only (no \r afterwards), the UNIX and Mac standard.
Positioned on line 1 after skip or autostart
This line is the autostart and not blank so searching up for the last non-blank ... line 1
Detecting sep ... Deducing this is a single column input.
Starting data input on line 1 (either column names or first row of data). First 10 characters: 1100110011
Some fields on line 1 are not type character (or are empty). Treating as a data row and using default column names.
Count of eol: 2 (including 0 at the end)
ncol==1 so sep count ignored
Type codes (point  0): 2
Column 1 ('V1') was detected as type 'integer64' but bumped to 'character' as requested by colClasses
Type codes: 4 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 4 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 1 column slots (1 - 0 dropped)
Read 2 rows. Exactly what was estimated and allocated up front
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map (rerun may be quicker)
   0.000s (  0%) sep and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Count rows (wc -l)
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection (100 rows at 10 points)
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation of 2x1 result (xMB) in RAM
   0.000s (  0%) Reading data
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation for type bumps (if any), including gc time if triggered
   0.000s (  0%) Coercing data already read in type bumps (if any)
   0.000s (  0%) Changing na.strings to NA
   0.001s        Total
```

This may help to analyse the issues with reading the variable with the 12 digits numerical code.